# LARAVEL - npm dependency missing (true-case-path) in "npm run watch"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I am working on a Laravel project(v8.12) on Windows 10 and I get this error when I try to run "npm run watch". The script was working fine a month ago and as it seems it stopped working properly after some changes made by other contributors. And here is the error with the call stack and everything:

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'true-case-path'
Require stack:
- C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js
- C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getSassImplementation.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at processResult (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:701:19)
    at C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:807:5
    at C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:156:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:250:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:223:4)
    at runCallbacks (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:27:15)
    at C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:200:4
    at C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:73:3)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
Notifications are disabled
Reason: DisabledForApplication Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.
Command Line: C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\node-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoretoast-x64.exe -appID "Laravel Mix" -pipeName \\.\pipe\notifierPipe-280d1750-a3b9-4181-9000-9ac0034b193a -p C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\laravel-mix\icons\la
ravel.png -m "Error: C:\Projects\subsearch\resources\sass\app.scss
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'true-case-path'
Require stack:
- C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js
- C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getSassImplementation.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (C:\Projects\subsearch\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)" -t "Laravel Mix"
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "tr-extract": "vue-gettext-cli extract -s ./resources/js/translations -d ./resources/js/translations -l nl",
        "tr-compile": "vue-gettext-cli compile -s ./resources/js/translations/locales -d ./resources/js/translations -c"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "6.0.13",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "sass": "^1.34.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.11.4",
        "@myena/advanced-select": "^0.9.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "laravel-vue-datatable": "^0.6.0",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "tailable-pagination": "^0.1.22",
        "v-calendar": "^2.3.0",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-easy-dnd": "^1.10.2",
        "vue-ellipsis": "^1.2.0",
        "vue-gettext": "^2.1.12",
        "vue-gettext-cli": "^1.0.5",
        "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-range-component-fixed": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-slider-component": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
        "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
        "vuetify": "^2.5.1"
    }
}
```

What I did so far - I ran "npm install" after deleting node_modules and package-lock.json.
As this didn't help I took more drastic measures:

1. Uninstall node.js
2. Remove all node and npm folders
3. Reboot
4. Install node.js again
5. Reboot again
6. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
7. Run npm install

But the error keeps occuring...
As node.js and npm are kind of a mystery to me, any help would be highly appreciated.

---

UPDATE

I am using node.js v16.4.0 and npm v7.18.1.

Comment: You've mistaken package.json with composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding the missing package ?

```
npm install true-case-path
```

or

```
yarn add true-case-path
```

Comment: Yes, I installed it locally and npm still can't find it.

Comment: Are you sure of that ? It don't appear on your packages.json

Comment: I've tried it and remove it from package.json.